# SQL boolean relationship

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a table `dislikes` which contains two columns, `idone` and `idtwo`.

These are unique ids' from users, for example:

```
| idone | idtwo |
-----------------
|   5   |   4   |
```

This means that user with `id=5` does not like user with `id=4`. What I have in PHP is an array containing the ids' of all the users that the current user has selected as not liking them.

So say `dislikes={1,2,3}`, this means that the current user does not like user 1,2, or 3. There is an unknown number of users in the database.

So if user 1 chooses to dislike user 2 and user 3 (this is done via HTML dropdown), I pass `dislike={2,3}` to a PHP page which processes this data.

I want the PHP page to then add entries `(1,2)` and `(1,3)`. Here is the first problem, how can I make sure only to add unique entries?

Also say that user 1 changes the fact that he dislikes user 2. Then I pass `dislike={3}` to the php page and must somehow remove all entries `(1,!3)`, i.e. all entries in which user 1 dislikes anyone except user 3. How can I achieve this? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Show your code ... what did you try? Does not sound that hard...

Comment: How many users are we talking? Could you always pass the complete dislike list to the php page, which could then remove all current records for that user, then add the new ones?

Comment: You have several options ... 1. Delete everything (user depended) and re-write was is currently valid. 2. Use (as already suggested) `REPLACE INTO`. 3. `INSERT INTO ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` ... and perhaps some more options I miss ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're using MySQL the easiest thing is probably to use [`REPLACE INTO`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) instead of `INSERT` with a primary key or unique index on the pair of columns (idone, idtwo).

Alternatively, on update, you can run a transaction that does any one of:

- Remove existing rows for this user, add all rows, commit
- Select existing rows, remove the rows from your local set that you would duplicate, add only new rows, commit

Comment: I see, I never knew about `REPLACE INTO`, but at the same time I also need to get rid of all other entries that are no longer disliked. Wouldn't the best way be to do the first option of your answer then?

Comment: @Dan: Yes, if you need to also remove rows then the simplest thing, in my opinion, is to remove all rows, and add back the ones you know about. Make sure you use a transaction.

Comment: Forgive my naivety, but what is a transaction?

Comment: @Dan: it guarantees that your sequence of several queries executes as one event, or the queries won't change your database: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/commit.html